# Any workaround to bypass megavideo limit of 72 minutes?

Tags: streaming

I am sure , this question might be illegal to some users. But I have got some documentary links posted on megavideo video site and unable to watch it because of its limitations of 72 minutes per day.

I Googled it and not able to find a better way.

Is there any workaround to get it work?

Comment: Would you clarify the "limitations of 72 hours per day"?

Comment: you can only watch 72hrs of video per day?

Comment: Well, that's not so bad for an average Earth day. But, who knows what planet he's living on ;-)

Comment: Btw, I believe he's talking about 72 minutes (but I still don't have the rep to rectify that).

Comment: Sounds like you want to view more than you can without a paid membership. Is that right?

Comment: @UK - You're right, you're gonna take a lot of heat for this question. Been there, done that...

Comment: My mistake , its not 72 hours :D , its 72 minutes , @e_ho I am not asking more than paid member.just to watch some documentary links i can't pay :)

Comment: You **are** asking about how to get around the payment method set up by the website by viewing more than free members are allowed.

Comment: AS I've mentioned it before, It might be breaking rules or policies against that site.But downloading youtube video's are also not legal. But aren't we doing those ?

Comment: Why this question has been closed ?

Comment: This question has been closed because it's about circumventing the payment method of a website and not a computer related question. Your argument about YouTube is hollow, that's not what your question is about at all.

Comment: @e_ho - it is the same thing. That is illegal (youtube) and so is this (what he's asking). But since many of us do that, we like to think of it as lesser evil. Sociologists have a name for that.

Comment: @ldigas Question was not about YouTube, it was about "breaking rules or policies against [Mega Video]". People torrent as well, but the question was not about torrents.

Comment: e_ho: "breaking rules or policies against mega video"=illegal, and "downloading from youtube"=illegal. Where is the difference then ?

Comment: @Idigas The question is not about YouTube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wait for 54 or 55 minutes like it says and continue watching? I know it's a hassle, but I'm sure there's a something you could be doing for a little under an hour... Like sufing SuperUser >_>

Comment: Yes, that's what i am doing now.But wanna know about any workarounds from SU.